# How do you use - 我还是做一枚安静的N 吧

Tags: grammar

Question for you all. I've seen sentences that are like this

我还是做一枚安静的吃货好了

or 
我还是做一枚安静的美少女

I understand that this is a funny expression (used primarily online) Can I replace the final word with any noun? For example, could I say

我还是做一枚安静的老外吧。?

Comment: Of course. It is pretty good actually!

Comment: What's its meaning?

Comment: @EnricoBrasil something like "(Facepalm) Let me be quiet and not get involved into that (ridiculous) thing XD."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a funny way of describing "I'll remain a spectator and not get involved in the matter", because "I'll never reach that level" or "I'll never do such a thing/achieve such a result".

You can definitely say "我还是做一枚安静的老外吧。" or replace it with any other nouns, but it depends on what the situation is. For example, if you see a Chinese guy doing something that you'll be never able to do, you can say "我还是做一枚安静的老外吧。" meaning you are amazed by the situation and will remain a foreigner and not try to achieve what he did...It's just a funny way of saying things.

It all comes from this saying "我只想做个安静的美男子(I only want to be a silent/low profile handsome guy" if you want to look more into it.

Comment: And why the measure word 枚？ Among  southern Chinese at least, I know it as a measure word for eggs, but not people!

Comment: @Ludi cute way of comparing people to object so it does not sound too serious